# Python PL/SQL making the dates be a variable that changes every day

Tags: python, sql, oracle, variables

So I have a connection that pulls data from a oracle db. I have a sql query that takes in a date and would like those two dates to be variables as those dates are supposed to be today's date and the last business date. I have already made the variables, I just don't know how I would go about putting them in the sql query. Thank you!

```
sql = "select v.*,d.portfolio_name
         from table(risk.gr_new_houston_pkg.PRICEVOL_TAB('12-Aug-2021','11-Aug-2021', 121, 1)) v
         LEFT JOIN (select * from table(risk.gr_function_pkg.get_portid_new (0, 121))) d on d.PCG_ID=v.PCG_ID"
cursor.execute(sql)
```

Comment: Well, I'm unsure of how to create bind variables in Python, however, if one of the variables is Today's Date, you can eliminate it by using TRUNC(SYSDATE).

Comment: Did you [read the documentation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html)?

Answer (score 0):

if I understood correctly, using format will help:

```
d_today = '12-Aug-2021'

d_business = '11-Aug-2021'

sql = "select v.*,d.portfolio_name
         from table(risk.gr_new_houston_pkg.PRICEVOL_TAB('{}','{}', 121, 1)) v
         LEFT JOIN (select * from table(risk.gr_function_pkg.get_portid_new (0, 121))) d on d.PCG_ID=v.PCG_ID".format(d_today, d_business)

cursor.execute(sql)
```